# Including a standard filename prefix for each csv file split from the original combined dataframe

Tags: r, csv

I am currently working on a large dataset which I have successfully split into separate csv files based on subject ID (code below):

```
# Splitting a data frame by a variable and saving separate csv files
dat <- read.csv("~/file/file_1/combinedfile.csv")

dat2 <- dat #make a copy of the dataframe to work from

spt2 <- split(dat2, dat2$ID) #create a 3rd dataframe by splitting the 2nd dataframe by ID

lapply(names(spt2), function(x){
  write_csv(spt2[[x]], path = paste(x, ".csv", sep = ""))
  }) #Write each split dataframe to its own csv file
```

I was wondering if there is a method for including a prefix (e.g. "part-" ) that is repeated for each csv file that I split from the original dataframe? (for example each file will be something like: part-01.csv, part-02.csv ...)

Comment: You can change this line: `write_csv(spt2[[x]], path = paste("part-", x, ".csv", sep = ""))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf` to build the path.

```
lapply(names(spt2), function(x){
  write.csv(spt2[[x]], sprintf("part-%s.csv", x), row.names = FALSE)
})
```